# How would I get all the Files in a bucket from Fire Storage and iterate through the files?

Tags: dart, flutter, firebase-storage

I am storing images in Firebase Storage, no more than 6/user. 
Its stored in bucket Photos/Userid/"Image_name"

The Image_name is either Photo1,2...6 depending on grid.index and thats all.

I've tried a bunch of methods to retrieve the bucket so i can iterate through 6 or less than 6 images in the bucket assigned to by user ID. I have not been successful. I am simply trying to take the 6 or <6 images and save them locally to an object File Photo1,2..6. I just cant seem to retrieve the things out of the storage bucket in reference. Any help would be nice.

```
StorageReference reference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('Photos/$Userid').child(photoindex);
//Upload the file to firebase
StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(file);
```

/*
Everything above works fine and the files are uploaded in their 
correct palaces. From another page when I want to pull the image and save it locally below is all i have. How could I iterate through the object Photos/UserId.
*/

```
StorageReference bucket = 
FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('Photos/$Userid');
```

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Storage client libraries currently don't have a way to list files under a path.  It's conventional to also store paths to files in a database so that you can query the database to get the list of files you're looking for.

A file list API is being considered by the Firebase team and may appear in the future, but it's my opinion that you still want to store paths to files in a database to make them easier to query and manage.  This is a common pattern in Firebase app architecture.

Comment: Thanks, Thats what i was thinking. Thought maybe it might be possible to just pull it straight